# Pattern matching the string either start and end with double quotes or should not have double quotes at all

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a pattern match, which should find string preceded or followed by the <, >, =, ,(, ) characters but the string may not have double quotes at all in starting and ending of it OR it may have double quotes on both starting and ending. Also we don't need to care case sensitivity. I got below code, its working, but its not working for the use case where string start and end with double quotes.

```
 
    import java.util.regex.*;
    public class Test 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            String where = "WHERE column1>10 and Column1 in (50,60) and \"Column1\"<100";
            String col = "Column1";

            String patern = "(?i:[<|>|=| |(|)]"+col+"[<|>|=| |(|)])";

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patern);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(where);
            while(m.find())
            {
                System.out.println("Found");
            }
        }
    }
```

### Output:

Found
Found

Expected output is, it should show thee times the 'Found', its not working for the double quotes use case.  Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you expect 3 times found? The string `Column1` only appears once, since matching is case-sensitive. Even if you change the case of `column1>10` to `Column1>10` you only have *two* occurrences.

Comment: Sorry I just corrected my where clause.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't get why you're using `|` inside character classes, but anyway, here's what you need.

```java
String where = "WHERE column1>10 and Column1 in (50,60) and \"Column1\"<100";
String affix = "[<>= ()]";
String column = "column1";

// this matches column either quoted or unquoted
String search = column + "|\"" + column + "\"";

String pattern = "(?i:" + (affix + search) + "|" + (search + affix) + ")";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(where);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println("Found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response @Leo Aso, If the where clause is below one:
String where = "WHERE column1>10 and Column1 in (50,60) and \"Column1\"<100"+
                            "this shoud not show \"=Column1\" and \"<Column1>\"";

Then it should not find last two matches which are - \"=Column1\" and \"<Column1>special\", but it it shows those matches also. I can go one search with double quotes and another without double quotes separately. But use case where - \"<Column1>special\" should not get match, I need to build patter for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use case: I want to replace the column names in the WHERE clause when user is renaming the column names, here is the final solution for the issue, it may be helpful for people who is looking for solution similar use case:

```
/**
 * Purpose: This method checks if the user has mapped any columns info, and user has 
 * provided different target name, then this method replaces the column name in WHERE clause 
 * with user mapped target column name. 
 * Eg: 
 * Where Clause: " WHERE customer_id > 100 and "customer_id" in (200,300) and ""customer_id""_SpecailColumn" <50 
 * User mapped customer_id to target_customer_id.
 * " WHERE target_customer_id > 100 and "target_customer_id" in (200,300) and ""customer_id""_SpecailColumn" <50
 * @param table
 */
public static void replaceColumnNamesInWhereClause(Table table)
{
    if(table.getTableColumns() != null)
    {
        //affix is the set of possible characters immediately followed by column name in WHERE clause, they are - <>= ()
        String affix = "[<>= ()]";
        String where = table.getSqlWhereClause();
        logger.info("Going to replace column names in table:"+table.getName()+
                " WHERE clause with user mapped target column names, where clause before replace:"+where);
        for(TableColumn tableColumn : table.getTableColumns())
        {
            String targetColumnName = tableColumn.getTargetName();
            String columnName = tableColumn.getName();
            //If target column name is empty then skip current column and got to next column.
            if(!StringUtils.isNotEmpty(tableColumn.getTargetName()) || targetColumnName.equalsIgnoreCase(columnName))
            {
                continue;
            }
            //Get list of double quoted strings with in WHERE clause
            List<String> specialStringsInWhereCaluse = DMUtils.getDoubleQuotedStringsInWhereCaluse(where);
            String regex = "(?i:" + affix + columnName + affix + ")";
            long count = 0;
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            //Get total number of patterns found in where clause.
            count = pattern.splitAsStream(where).count();
            //Do the pattern search and replace, repeat it based on number of patterns found in original WHERE clause
            //We need to depend on number of patterns found count, instead of not Matcher.found() options, because if the WHERE has the special string
            // which has column name within that then it always says Matcher.found() as true, so it will become infinite loop.
            while(count > 0)
            {
                //If the column name has already double quotes then go to next while loop.
                if(targetColumnName.charAt(0) == '"' && targetColumnName.charAt(targetColumnName.length()) == '"')
                {
                    break;
                }
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(where);
                if(matcher.find())
                {
                    String foundColumnName = where.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end());
                    //We are have to make sure that the column name is not part of another double quoted string.
                    //eg. customer_id, but where clause is - " WHERE customer_id > 100 and ""customer_id""_SpecailColumn"
                    //In the above example "customer_id""_SpecailColumn" is the column name, so we don't want to replace this specific use case.
                    boolean replace = true;
                    for(String str: specialStringsInWhereCaluse)
                    {
                        //customer_id found in "customer_id""_SpecailColumn"
                        //We don't need to replace this use case.
                        boolean contains = str.contains(foundColumnName);
                        if(contains && str.length() != foundColumnName.length())
                        {
                            replace = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Replace only if column is not part of within special strings.
                    if(replace)
                    {
                        where = where.substring(0, matcher.start()+1) + tableColumn.getValidTargetName() +  where.substring(matcher.end()-1, where.length());
                    }
                }
                count --;
            }

            //This use case to find the column name with double quotes. Sometimes use put double quotes around column name in WHERE Clause.
            //we cann't make these two cases in single regular expression.
            count = 0;
            String regexDQ;
            if(columnName.charAt(0) == '"' && columnName.charAt(columnName.length()) == '"')
            {
                regexDQ = "(?i:" + affix + columnName + affix + ")";
            }
            else
            {
                regexDQ = "(?i:" + affix + "\""+ columnName +"\"" + affix + ")";
            }
            Pattern patternDQ = Pattern.compile(regexDQ);
            count = patternDQ.splitAsStream(where).count();
            //Do the pattern search and replace, repeat it based on number of patterns found in original WHERE clause
            while(count > 0)
            {
                Matcher matcherDQ = patternDQ.matcher(where);
                if(matcherDQ.find())
                {
                    String foundColumnName = where.substring(matcherDQ.start(),matcherDQ.end());
                    boolean replace = true;
                    for(String str: specialStringsInWhereCaluse)
                    {
                        //We are have to make sure that the column name is not part of another double quoted string.
                        //eg. "customer_id", but where clause is - " WHERE "customer_id" > 100 and ""customer_id""_SpecailColumn"
                        //In the above example "customer_id""_SpecailColumn" is the column name, so we don't want to replace this specific use case.
                        boolean contains = str.contains(foundColumnName);
                        if(contains && str.length() != foundColumnName.length())
                        {
                            replace = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Replace only if column is not part of within special strings.
                    if(replace)
                    {
                        where = where.substring(0, matcherDQ.start()+2) + tableColumn.getValidTargetName() +  where.substring(matcherDQ.end()-2, where.length());
                    }
                }
                count--;
            }
        }
        table.setSqlWhereClause(where);
        logger.info("Column names in table:"+table.getName()+
                " WHERE clause replaced with user mapped target column names, where clause after replace:"+where);
    }
}
/**
 * Purpose: This method takes the WHERE clause and identified if there are any double quoted strings
 * are present with in the WHERE clause, it does not consider "" as a string as Teradata considered 
 * "" as " in object name.
 * @param whereCaluse
 * @return
 */
public static List<String> getDoubleQuotedStringsInWhereCaluse(String whereCaluse)
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean stringStarted = false, stringEnded = false;
    String quotedString = "";
    for(int i=0; i<whereCaluse.length(); i++)
    {
        if(whereCaluse.charAt(i) == '"')
        {
            if(!stringStarted)
            {
                stringStarted = true;
            }
            else if(!(whereCaluse.charAt(i-1) == '"'))
            {
                stringEnded = true;
            }

        }
        if(stringStarted && !stringEnded)
        {
            quotedString = quotedString + whereCaluse.charAt(i);
        }
        if(stringEnded)
        {
            quotedString = quotedString + whereCaluse.charAt(i);
            list.add(quotedString);
            stringStarted = false; stringEnded = false;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```